# Eclipse CDT: Ctrl-I indentation inconsistent with Code Formatter rules

Tags: eclipse, indentation, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting

I'm experiencing some weird behavior in Eclipse CDT (Mars, v4.5.1). The indentation applied to function bodies by the Ctrl-I ("Fix Indentation") command does not obey the formatting rules specified by the Code Formatter; specifically, it adds an unnecessary extra level of indentation. For example, if I write the following code:

```cpp
int MyClass::foo(int a) {
int x = 2;
x = x * a;
return x;
}
```

highlight it, and hit Ctrl-Shift-F, I get this:

```cpp
int MyClass::foo(int a) {
    int x = 2;
    x = x * a;
    return x;
}
```

On the other hand, if I hit Ctrl-I, I get this:

```cpp
int MyClass::foo(int a) {
        int x = 2;
        x = x * a;
        return x;
}
```

Note that there are now two levels of indentation, since the indentation level is 4 spaces.

If I highlight code that has already been formatted by Code Formatter (like the first example) and press Ctrl-I, it adds an extra 4 spaces to each line so that it looks like the second example. Conversely, if I highlight code that looks like the second example and press Ctrl-Shift-F, it removes the extra indentation so it looks like  the first example.

Furthermore, if I begin typing a new function definition (i.e. `void foo() {`) and hit Enter, Eclipse automatically indents the next line by 8 spaces, not 4. After I type code, I have to highlight it and hit Ctrl-Shift-F to remove the extra indentation.

In my C++ Code Formatter preferences, I have Indentation Size = 4, Tab Size = 4, and Tab Policy = Spaces Only. As far as I can tell, this is the only place to set indentation preferences. So why don't Ctrl-I or automatic indentation respect them?

Comment: Sounds like a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT). [Contributions welcome!](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing)

Comment: Should not it be doing it automatically. I generally use shift+tab or the source menu

Comment: Did you file a bug report?